# Meta-properties with groovy?

Tags: python, groovy, metaprogramming

In python ( specifically CherryPy ) I can do something like

```
class Root(Object):

  def index():
   #some sort of logic here

  index.expose = True
```

is there something similar for Groovy?

## Update

CherryPy use's plain objects for it's equivalent of controllers, where the developer decorates or marks each method that should be exposed to the URL routing system.  In the above example ( with some additional configuration ), the .expose property tells the framework that index should be accessible viable the request routing system.
    Specifically for my problem, I'm trying to write a data dictionary that pushes abbreviated key, value pairs onto a simple class from a vCard file.  So ideally something like

```
 class Foo {
    @Key("FN")
    def fullName
 }
```

where a vCard parser would create a new instance of foo then assign the FullName class property with the contents of "FN".

Comment: most readers probably aren't familiar with CherryPy, so you're more likely to get answers if you just describe what it is that you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more research ( Google ), I ended up checking r/Groovy on reddit and was led to [this](http://www.mengu.net/post/annotating-your-grails-controller-classes-and-actions) very useful blog post

From my perspectives, Java annotations can be used to decorate or markup methods with extended logic.  So something like

```
 class Root {
    @Expose
    void index() {
      #som sort of logic here
    }
 }
```

And then use Java annotations to detect the @Expose annotation.